# Just another SQL case (GROUP BY)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm stuck on an SQL problem that I don't know how to solve.

Let's say I have a table like this (concerning estimations on house prices):

```
estimationID | estimationDate | userID | cityID

1            | '2020-01-01'   | 123456 | 987654
2            | '2020-12-01'   | 135790 | 975310
...
```

With estimationDate being the date when the estimation was made, userID the ID of the user who made the estimation and cityID the ID of the city where the estimation was made.

I need to get the maximum number of estimations made by one user (I don't care which one, I don't need an ID) for each city.

Something like

```
SELECT cityID,*maximum number of estimations made by one user from this city* FROM estimationsTable GROUP BY cityID
```

Any idea?

Comment: hey, the question is well laid out, but the title could be improved to summarise your question.

Comment: Alright sorry, was uninspired for the title x)

Comment: Its no problem, just trying to help for next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step:

1. Get the number of estimations per user and city.
2. Get the maximum of these numbers per city.

The query:

```
select cityid, max(cnt)
from
(
  select cityid, userid, count(*) as cnt
  from estimationstable 
  group by cityid, userid
) counted
group by cityid
order by cityid;
```

Comment: Ooooh thanks mate, didn't know you could GROUP BY on two columns! Perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
  with cte as (
     select userid,cityid,count(*) as cnt
    from table_name group by userid,cityid
    ) 
   , cte2 as (
     select *,
     row_number() over(partition by cityid order by cnt desc) rn 
     from cte 
   ) select * from cte2 where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

sol 1:

```
SELECT id, MAX(maximum_number_of_estimations)
      FROM (SELECT id,COUNT(*) AS maximum_number_of_estimations
              FROM TABLE x)group by id as final_query
```

sol2:

```
use order by Count DESC with group by`
```

something like this should work
the idea is you count all the occurrences in the inner query with the group by on your id and another query to get the max of it OR you use `ORDER BY [Field] DESC`
with `GROUP BY` which will automatically put the highest ones on the top

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, I think you can do this without a subquery:

```
select distinct cityid,
       (array_agg(userid order by count(*) desc, userid))[ordinal(1)] as userid,
       max(count(*)) over (order by count(*) desc) as cnt
from estimationstable 
group by cityid, userid
```